# Can I use PowerShell to add a Logic App that appears in VM Tasks section?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-logic-apps

I would like to start and shut down certain Azure machines using Logic app tasks. When I navigate to the VM, open "Tasks (preview)" and create a task from that view, it appears in the list of tasks under that VM:

[image]

When I use a template and PowerShell to deploy the same Logic app which points to a different VM name, the task doesn't appear on "Tasks (preview)" page.

Where is that connection made and is it possible to add that using PowerShell?

I've tried using Get-AzLogicApp of the logic apps I created manually and automatically but I couldn't find where that connection is made.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having a customized flow in your logic app, then you can create a task in your new virtual machine and copy the schema of your already existing logic app to the newly created one.

Alternatively, you can get this done by exporting your task template first by navigating to your resource group and search for the Task that you have added in your Virtual Machine.

[image]

**Task Logic App >> Overview >> Export >> Export to Automation Task**

[image]

Finally, you can provide the details and download the template.

Now you can upload the template to Github and create a pull request so that the Azure Logic Apps team will review your pull request.

*Reference taken from : [Create automation tasks to manage and monitor Azure resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/create-automation-tasks-azure-resources#create-pull-request)*